# How to drop duplicates for the following data-frame based on multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i am having a dataframe as follows:

`df`

| cylce | csec | dist | vel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -40.1 | 9.87 | 2.7 |
| 1 | -40.1 | 9.89 | 2.2 |
| 2 | -39.1 | 14.07 | 2.0 |
| 2 | -39.1 | 14.09 | 2.8 |
| 3 | -38.7 | 18.09 | 3.2 |
| 4 | -36.6 | 15.37 | 0.5 |
| 4 | -38.01 | 16.23 | 1.8 |
| 4 | -38.4 | 16.66 | 3.1 |

```
i have to drop the duplicate cycle based on some conditions:  
    -if the csec is same then  
            -look for the  dist and keep the row with highest dist  
                   -if dist are same check the vel ,keep the row with highest vel  
    -if csec is different
            -keep the row with highest csec
```

`output`

| cylce | csec | dist | vel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -40.1 | 9.89 | 2.2 |
| 2 | -39.1 | 14.09 | 2.8 |
| 3 | -38.7 | 18.09 | 3.2 |
| 4 | -36.6 | 15.37 | 0.5 |

I was able to get the dupicate rows with following code

```
    duplicate_cyle = df[df.duplicated('cycle',keep = False)]
```

I would like to know how to drop the rows based on the conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort your dataframe in descending order of csec, dist and vel, then drop duplictes, eg:

```
out = (
    df.sort_values(['cycle', 'csec', 'dist', 'vel'], ascending=[True, False, False, False])
    .drop_duplicates(subset=['cycle'])
)
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you can explain little more

Comment: @Mageo What do you feel needs explaining?

Comment: inside ascending,only one is set to be True,why?

Comment: That's to keep it in cycle order... the rest are to prioritise the highest csec within a cycle, and where there's a tie on csec,  the highest dist, and where there's a tie on dist then the highest vel

Comment: Instead of keeping the cycle with highest dist when csec is same,how to keep the lowest dist when csec is same?and if the dist is same keep the highest vel

Comment: Change the sort order for dist to be ascending instead of descending @Mageo